# Program doesn't run on the editor (sublime, atom) and shut down for using 13 CPU second on the web editor

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm still beginner with programming therefore the next code is made for learning purposes.

Given your birthday and the current date, calculate your age 
in days. Compensate for leap days. Assume that the birthday 
and current date are correct dates (and no time travel). Simply put, if you were born 1 Jan 2012 and todays date is 
2 Jan 2012 you are 1 day old.

Trying to solve this problem I have come up with 2 different approaches but both of them don't run, it does not print even none or -1, it does just nothing. the worst part (I will like to know the reason) is that after running it, my computer start to slow down, so then I need to reset or shut down my PC (surface book 2, so I don't think is a hardware issue). Did I install python correctly?

Here is the code:

```
daysOfMonths = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

def isLeapYear(year):
    if year % 4 != 0:
        return False
    elif year % 100 != 0:
        return True
    elif year % 400 != 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def next_date(year, month, day):
    day += 1
    if isLeapYear(year) == True:
        daysOfMonths[1] = 29
    elif day > daysOfMonths[month-1]:
        day = 1
        month += 1
    elif month > 12:
        month = 1
        year += 1
    return year, month, day


def daysBetweenDates(y1, m1, d1, y2, m2, d2):
    days = 0
    while [y1, m1, d1] < [y2, m2, d2]:
        y1, m1, d1 = next_date(y1, m1, d1)
        days += 1
    return days

print daysBetweenDates(2000,01,10,2001,01,12)
```

I have search for answers but usually when the problem is similar to mine, the answers are either related to debugging or that the loop if going infinite but I have already tested the function `isLeapYear` and `next_date`. I have also make sure that the while does not go to infinite by adding one date to the first date with the function next_date and telling the computer to stop when the date 1 and 2 are same.

Comment: Can you use the `datetime` module?

Comment: Also, I really don't understand the title of your question. I suggest making that more clear. And please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: This is the first time I use Stack, but I already correct the indentation. what I mean by the question is that when I run the code either in atom or sublime, the program doesn't run, and when I run it in a web editor(Udacity web page) it shows me the error "Program shut down for using 13 CPU second on the web editor"

Comment: *"the worst part (I will like to know the reason) is that after running it, my computer start to slow down, so then I need to reset or shut down my PC"* that's what happens when your program gets stuck into an infinite loop. There's no need to restart your computer, you can just interrupt your program (Ctrl-C will do if you are running it into a terminal, otherwise there'll be some stop button in your IDE if you are running it from an IDE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-inventing the wheel. you can use python's standard library [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) to perform various operations on dates

**Implementation:**

```
from datetime import datetime

def days_between_dates(date_1, date_2):
    # date format: MM/DD/YYYY you can change to whatever format you need
    date_format = "%m/%d/%Y"
    # convert given date string to python datetime objects
    date_1_object = datetime.strptime(date_1, date_format)
    date_2_object = datetime.strptime(date_2, date_format)

    # substracting date_1 from date_2 result python datetime delta object
    delta = date_2_object - date_1_object

    # return number of days in integer format from delta object
    return delta.days
```

**Usage:**

```
days_between_dates('12/12/2018', '12/12/2018') # returns 0
days_between_dates('12/12/2018', '12/13/2018') # returns 1
days_between_dates('12/12/2017', '12/12/2018') # returns 365
```

**Reason why your code not working**

The implementation of `next_year` function is wrong. The bugs are

1. statement `daysOfMonths[1] = 29` changes `daysOfMonths` forever which means for all years after first leap year `daysOfMonths[1]` will be `29` which we don't want. Solution for this is maintaing two seperate `daysOfMonths` list or putting `daysOfMonths[1]` value to `28` back.
2. `next_date(2000,1,31)` returns `(2000, 1, 32)` but it supposed to be `(2000, 2, 1)`. Its happening because `elif`. If year is leap year then 2nd , 3rd conditions `day > daysOfMonths[month-1]` , `month > 12` won't execute because they are in `elif` but we want to check those conditions even for leap year. The solution for this is not putting them in `elif` block so that all conditions will execute always.

The correct implementation of `next_year` will be

```
commonYear = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
leapYear = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
def next_date(year, month, day):
    day += 1
    daysOfMonths = commonYear
    if isLeapYear(year) == True:
        daysOfMonths = leapYear
    if day > daysOfMonths[month-1]:
        day = 1
        month += 1
    if month > 12:
        month = 1
        year += 1
    return year, month, day
```

why your program not running in editors ? it may be because while loop becoming infinite loop causing program not to return anything in your editors. but web editors can detect infinite loops and will kill the process

Comment: thanks, for your help, but as I said in the post, this is for learning purposes so therefore I want to make it work just with the things I have learned.

I really don't know why the program doesn't run in editors actually that's the think that keeps me thinking, now I could fix the problem by adding a helper function, but I'm still struggling why it didn't work that way

Comment: @JosephArcila I modified answer for why your code not working, check it

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was really complete and I understand it all